# Gap: Determinant with Indeterminate()

Tags: gap

This is probably very easy but can't figure it out. How can I compute
the determininant of a matrix with indeterminate entries in it?

```
gap> a:=X(Rationals);
x_1
gap> m:=[[a,0],[0,a]];
[ [ x_1, 0 ], [ 0, x_1 ] ]
gap> DeterminantMat(m);
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for `DeterminantMat' on 1 arguments at /usr/src/gap-4.10.2/lib/methsel2.g:250 called from
<function "HANDLE_METHOD_NOT_FOUND">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:23
type 'quit;' to quit to outer loop
brk>
```

I would have expected the answer to be
`x_1^2`.
Needless to say that `DeterminantMat(m)` works as expected when there are no indeterminates in `m` as does

```
gap> RootsOfPolynomial(a^2+2*a+1);
[ -1, -1 ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the matrix `m` is not actually a matrix in the GAP sense, where it is required that all entries live in the same ring: but you are mixing integers with polynomials here. To fix this, you can replace the `0` entries by `Zero(a)`; or just multiply the whole matrix with the 1 polynomial.

```
gap> a:=X(Rationals);
x_1
gap> m:=[[a,0],[0,a]];
[ [ x_1, 0 ], [ 0, x_1 ] ]
gap> IsMatrix(m);
false
gap> m:=[[a,0],[0,a]] * One(a);
[ [ x_1, 0 ], [ 0, x_1 ] ]
gap> IsMatrix(m);
true
gap> DeterminantMat(m);
x_1^2
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of something like that. But then I changed ```a:=X(Rationals)``` to ```a:=X(Integers)``` to no avail. Why doesn't that work or, to put it differently, over what ring would a matrix like ```[[1,0],[0,1]]``` be?

Comment: That's over the ring of integers. But in GAP, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are not a subset of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Incidentally, they are not in my undergrad course, either: a constant polynomial is not the same as a constant polynomial function is not the same as its constant value (I even point out that the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ strictly speaking is artificial, albeit convenient).

Comment: Makes sense. I hadn't thought of ```x_1``` as a polynomial although you clearly said so in your answer. I had the notion of it being a variable. So is it then the right way to state the problem of a parameter dependent determinant of a matrix?

Comment: `DeterminantMatDivFree` works for `X(Integers)` - there is a suggestion about it in the manual entry for `DeterminantMat` - enter `?DeterminantMat` in GAP to see it.

Comment: No, it does not (I actually had `DeterminantMatDivFree` in the first version of my answer that I never submitted). Also, `X(Integers)` is identical to `X(Rationals)`.

Comment: `DeterminantMatDivFree` does work for `X(Integers)` in the example above. But thanks for pointing out that `X(Integers)` is identical to `X(Rationals)` - that explains why it actually works.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov ```DeterminantMatDivFree``` does not work for ```X(Integers)``` here…
```a:=X(Integers);; m:=[[a,0],[0,a]];;DeterminantMatDivFree(m);``` results in the same error as above.
```

Comment: @diffset sorry, was imprecise - I meant that it works in @Max's example, i.e. after `One(a);` - but then `DeterminantMat` works too, so it does not make a difference...